# Изменить текст оплаты woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Сложно как-то описать, к примеру через paypal человек оплатил товар, и мне в кошелек пришли деньги с названием сайта и номером заказа. Можно ли это как-то отредактировать?

Вот к примеру в paypal, мне надо убрать номер заказа:
[image: Пример]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Можно. Чтобы ответить более предметно, а не играть в угадайку - нужно знать больше, чем написано в вопросе.

Comment: @SeVlad мне надо изменить сообщение, которое приходит после оплаты, к примеру в том же пейпале я скрин сделал. В самой админке я не нашел, поэтому скорее всего где-то в коде это хранится, хотелось бы чтобы пустое сообщение приходило с оплатой, или измененное. Сейчас там название сайта и номер заказа.